# How do I fetch the attachments from an AttachmentsField control?

Tags: custom-form, attachments, aspx

In WSS 3.0, I've got an edit form which includes an `AttachmentsField` control. It corresponds to the list of existing attachments, with delete links. In a normal edit form, if you delete an attachment and hit Save, it'll then remove the attachment.

I want to replicate this functionality for something similar, but I'm unsure how to extract the current list of attachments stored *in the control*. I need to do this in order to reflect any changes based on that.

The `Value` property of the `AttachmentsField` is apparently null, whether or not there are any attachments and whether or not I've made any changes on the control. If I check `AttachmentsField.Controls` and recursively loop through it, there's a `Literal` in it with an ID of `AttachmentsList`, but I'm not sure how to extract the data from it (it errors if I try to print its `Text` property). I can't find any other avenues of entry to try and access the data.

**How do I extract the list of attachments currently rendered in the AttachmentsField control**?

Comment: Are you trying to use this control on in server-side code, JavaScript, XSLT. How are you trying to get the values?

Comment: @Chris Currently? C# server-side. I'm open to anything that'll prevent me from having to create my own pseudo-AttachmentsField control as a workaround for this edit form.

Answer (score 3):

I had a glance in the [`AttachmentsField.UpdateFieldValueInItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.attachmentsfield.updatefieldvalueinitem.aspx) call to see where it gets the list of files from for its own use.

It appears to use this property: `AttachmentsField.Context.Request.Files`, the documentation for which is here:

[HttpRequest.Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/system.web.httprequest.files)

Edit: I suddenly realised that you may be trying to access the control in order to save the attachments. If that's the case then [`AttachmentsField.UpdateFieldValueInItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.attachmentsfield.updatefieldvalueinitem.aspx) is in itself the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at a custom EditForm.aspx page in Sharepoint Designer, the form code looks like this:

```
<tr id="idAttachmentsRow">
 <td nowrap="true" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" width="20%">
  <SharePoint:FieldLabel ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Attachments" runat="server"/>
 </td>
 <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="80%">
  <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="AttachmentsField" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Attachments" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u','AttachmentsField','Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Attachments')}"/>
   <script>
      var elm = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable");
      if (elm == null || elm.rows.length == 0)
      document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow").style.display='none';
   </script>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Wouldn't you want to mimmic that code?

Edit: Attaching a file to a list item results in default EditForm code like this:

```
<TABLE border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 id=idAttachmentsTable>
            <TR id={7D99341E-8DFE-4EC1-83E9-46B1AAECFA71}><TD class="ms-vb"><span dir="ltr"><a tabindex=1 onclick="DispDocItemEx(this, 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3')" href="https://my.domain.com/sites/spsite/Lists/Calendar/Attachments/3/features.xls">features.xls</a></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD class="ms-propertysheet"><IMG alt='Delete' SRC="/_layouts/images/rect.gif">&nbsp;<a tabindex=1 href="javascript:RemoveAttachmentFromServer('{7D99341E-8DFE-4EC1-83E9-46B1AAECFA71}',1)">Delete</a></TD></TR>
        </TABLE>
```

What do you want to do with the files?

Comment: I mimicked that in the past, but that just gets you the control. It doesn't really explain how to get the attachments *from* the control.

Comment: Since it returns a table with an id of idAttachmentsTable, you could use some client side script to do something with it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you want to retrieve the list of attachments of current list item in server-side code. In such a case there is [Attachments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.attachments.aspx) property of SPListItem.

Comment: No, I would like to retrieve the list of attachments of the current list item as rendered in the AttachmentsField control. `Attachments` on the SPListItem doesn't update until the form is submitted, and I can't submit that data to update the attachments if I can't properly read the AttachmentsField control.

Comment: Then I have no idea, but you will probably need to do it on client-side e.g. via JQuery